# Windows 10 uwp blurred title bar

Tags: uwp, blur, titlebar

I tried to make the title bar blurred and I visited [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/acrylic) page and added code shown below

```
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
```

but the error is shown and I don't know how to solve this

[image: This is the error image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in App(). You should avoid doing anything there.

The best place to suggest would be to use your first page OnNavigatedTo method. Possibly you can do that OnLaunched, but I haven't tested that, as page that you have linked suggests using App.xaml.cs it probably means OnLaunched, I am not sure if that is always the best practice as your app might open multiple windows and then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code in `OnLaunched` or `OnActivated` method in App.xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
}
```